# Sign outgoing message

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web-services, digital-signature

I'm trying to get my head around WCF and have a test scenario where i want to receive an unsigned SOAP message process it and return a signed SOAP message, where the body is signed.

Therefore, how do I add a public/private key pair to the WCF service for it to utilize in signing?

Secondly, how would I add a digital signature to the outgoing message signing the body only.

I'm using a custom SOAP1.1 with WS-addressing binding.

I'm using C#.

Answer (score 1):

What service are you signing your message for? If it's for Amazon, then this article provides a nice tutorial: [Signing Amazon Product Advertising API requests — the missing C# WCF](http://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/).

Answer (score 1):

Just seen this post and not sure if it is still relevant but it helps anyone else:

```
[Serviceinstance].ChannelFactory.EndPoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel =
    Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign
```